# Eve: exposed fieldsets don't appear?

Tags: python, eve

I'm having trouble accessing fields in my schema when using the "datasource" and "filter" domain attributes.

So, I have a number of "nodes" in my database, with sub "categories" which I'm matching via $eq, including one category called "event".  I've put a few "events" in the database, each with a "category" (for matching), and a "name".  (I have some other fields too, but I've edited for brevity.)

As you can see in the GET request to the `/nodes` endpoint below, the "name" shows up correctly: it's in the database OK.  But when I access an event via the `/events` endpoint, the match works correctly, but "name" is nowhere to be seen.

[In the docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html) it says *"by default API responses to GET requests will include all fields defined by the corresponding resource schema. The projection setting of the datasource resource keyword allows you to redefine the fieldset."*

If I put in a projection setting for "name", indeed I can see the "name" field in a GET request, but isn't that supposed to be the default?  Also, PATCH and POST requests totally fail in any case, which makes the endpoint pretty useless.

Thanks for any ideas.  Python 3.5.3, Eve 0.7

`settings.py`:

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
AUTO_CREATE_LISTS = True
XML = False
IF_MATCH = False
X_DOMAINS = '*'

headers = ['Content-Type']
X_HEADERS = headers
X_EXPOSE_HEADERS = headers

DOMAIN = {
    'nodes': {
        'schema': {
            'name': {'type': 'string'},
            'category': {
                'type': 'list',
                'required': True,
                'allowed': [
                    'person',
                    'place',
                    'event',
                ]
            },
        }
    },
    'events': {
        'datasource': {
            'source': 'nodes',
            'filter': {
                'category': {'$eq': 'event'}
            }
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

`$ curl localhost:5000/nodes`

```
{
   "_items" : [

      ...

      {
         "_links" : {
            "self" : {
               "title" : "Node",
               "href" : "nodes/58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a"
            }
         },
         "_id" : "58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a",
         "_updated" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT",
         "name" : "What a Neat Exhibition",
         "category" : [
            "event"
         ],
         "_created" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT",
      }
   ],
   "_links" : {
      "self" : {
         "href" : "nodes",
         "title" : "nodes"
      },
      "parent" : {
         "title" : "home",
         "href" : "/"
      }
   },
   "_meta" : {
      "max_results" : 25,
      "total" : 6,
      "page" : 1
   }
}
```

`$ curl localhost:5000/events`

```
{
   "_items" : [

    ...

      {
         "_updated" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT",
         "_id" : "58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a",
         "_links" : {
            "self" : {
               "href" : "events/58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a",
               "title" : "Event"
            }
         },
         "_created" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT"
      }
   ],
   "_meta" : {
      "page" : 1,
      "total" : 3,
      "max_results" : 25
   },
   "_links" : {
      "self" : {
         "href" : "events",
         "title" : "events"
      },
      "parent" : {
         "href" : "/",
         "title" : "home"
      }
   }
}
```

`$ curl localhost:5000/events/58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a`

```
{
   "_updated" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT",
   "_created" : "Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:53:40 GMT",
   "_links" : {
      "self" : {
         "title" : "Event",
         "href" : "events/58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a"
      },
      "parent" : {
         "href" : "/",
         "title" : "home"
      },
      "collection" : {
         "href" : "events",
         "title" : "events"
      }
   },
   "_id" : "58abc7d4b6bc6595ecf9208a"
}
```